# I will like to return the previous object and the next object of a matching object id in node

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Please i am new to node js and MongoDB.
When i want to retrieve a post by id, i want to be able to retrieve the previous post and next post also.
this is my post, it only retrieves the current post by id.

```
Post.findById(req.params.postId)
    .then((existingpost) => {
        console.log(Post.find(req.params.postId))
      if (existingpost) {
        res.send(existingpost);
      }
      return res.status(404).send({
        message: "Post does not exist with id " + req.params.postId,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.kind === "ObjectId") {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Post does not exist with id " + req.params.postId,
        });
      }
      return res.status(500).send({
        message:
          "Some error occurred while retrieving the post with postId " +
          req.params.postId,
      });
    });
};
```

I currently receive the object with the id like this which is fine.

```
{
    "_id": "6009f3e294d8a033402a76e7",
    "title": "Covid 19 in Italy",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-21T21:36:34.514Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-21T21:36:34.514Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

But i will love to receive the object of the current id, the previous object and the next object.
something like this.

```
[{
    "_id": "3230g5e382d8a033402a76e7",
    "title": "Effect of Covid on the Economy",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-21T21:36:34.514Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-21T21:36:34.514Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "6009f3e294d8a033402a76e7",
    "title": "Covid 19 in Italy",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-21T21:36:34.514Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-21T21:36:34.514Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "4567hye294d8a033402a76e7",
    "title": "Life after Covid",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "createdAt": "2021-01-21T21:36:34.514Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-01-21T21:36:34.514Z",
    "__v": 0
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is there any straight way to do this, you can try aggregation,

**Using UUID and CreatedAt:**

- `$facet` to get all documents in `all` after sorting in ascending order by `createdAt`
- `$let` to define vars `states` with start and total documents,
- `$cond` check condition if index of input uuid is zero then return `start: 0` and `total: 2` documents we have to slice from all array, else get current index and subtract minus 1 and `total: 3`
- `in` to return slice documents on the base of `start` and `total`

```
Post.aggregate([
  { $facet: { all: [{ $sort: { createdAt: 1 } }] } },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            states: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: [{ $indexOfArray: ["$all._id", req.params.postId] }, 0] },
                { start: 0, total: 2 },
                {
                  start: {
                    $subtract: [{ $indexOfArray: ["$all._id", req.params.postId] }, 1]
                  },
                  total: 3
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          in: { $slice: ["$all", "$$states.start", "$$states.total"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DVON8kI60XU)

---

**Using ObjectID:**

- convert your string input id `req.params.postId` to object id using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`
- `$facet` to separate result,
- first, `$match` to get current and next documents, `$sort` `_id` in descending order, `$limit` 2
- second, `$match` to get previous document, `$sort` `_id` in descending order, `$limit` 1
- `$project` to get result after concat both array `first` and `second` using `$concatArrays`

```
req.params.postId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.postId);
Post.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      first: [
        { $match: { _id: { $gte: req.params.postId } } },
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
        { $limit: 2 }
      ],
      second: [
        { $match: { _id: { $lt: req.params.postId } } },
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $project: { result: { $concatArrays: ["$first", "$second"] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dVajoevSY5X)

Comment: Is that a ObjectId or UUID? If its UUID, how would you compare!! O.o. Might be it's an ObjectId, since he post as  a String, I raised this ques.

Comment: OP has mention in title that is object id, that is good point i have to concert it to object if he post string, but i don't know how to deal with UUID you have any clue?.

Comment: I just think of having index or (may go with created date also). Working https://mongoplayground.net/p/f3Mc6nUk8Qv. Might be a long method

Comment: @turivishal Thanks for the code. The above id isnt a structured id, it is uuid.

Comment: @turivishal I jsut posted my answer since he said its a uuid. Whatever both answers are correct depending on the _id type

Comment: @varman no problem, i have just added one more approach on the base uuid and createdAt. is it correct way?

Comment: @OlayinkaJosephBolaji ok i have updated second approach as per uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a UUID, this approach might help you..

- `$sort` to sort the documents by asc
- `$group` and `$unwind` to get the index
- `$facet` to categorize the incoming data into `current` and `allDocs`
- We know current is only one object, so we do `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- We already know the index, so we use `$filter` to get prev, current and next using index
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$replaceRoot` to make the objects to the root

Here is the script

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   $sort: { createdAt: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT"}
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: "$data", includeArrayIndex: "index" } },
  {
    $facet: {
      current: [
        { $match: { "data._id": "3230g5e382d8a033402a76e7" } }
      ],
      allDocs: [
        { $match: {} }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$current"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      docs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$allDocs",
          cond: {
            $or: [
              { $eq: [ "$$this.index", { $subtract: [ "$current.index", 1 ] } ] },
              { $eq: [ "$$this.index", "$current.index" ] },
              { $eq: [ "$$this.index", { $add: [ "$current.index", 1 ] } ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$docs" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$docs.data" } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f3Mc6nUk8Qv)**

There are many ways to do this, this is one of the way. If you feel you have a lot of document, then try to avoid `$unwind` which is expensive, in that case you can try using `createdDate` instead of index